# Class not found Exception - Maven Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have created dyamic web project with Maven.
I have used [jfairy](https://github.com/Codearte/jfairy) fake data generator plugin as maven in my pom.xml like as below :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.codearte.jfairy</groupId>
    <artifactId>jfairy</artifactId>
    <version>0.5.3</version>
</dependency>
```

But I got the error like as below:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/codearte/jfairy/Fairy
at dao.Users.InsertUser(Users.java:20)
at model.UserManager.InsertUsers(UserManager.java:19)
at contoller.InsertUsers.doPost(InsertUsers.java:38)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:509)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1104)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

So advice me on it.

Comment: Try clean build the application

Comment: can you check if the jar is actually downloaded?

Comment: Go to Project properties > Deployment Assembley > Add > Java Build Path Entries > maven , Apply

Comment: Have you done the installation as instructed in the jfairy README.md? It says to run `./gradlew build` and `./gradlew publishToMavenLocal`

Comment: Hi @n j,
I have tried your option but it'll stop my project like : Not found.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse maven integration not working well. You can go to project directory and run this command :

```
mvn eclipse:clean
mvn eclipse:eclipse
mvn install
```

In other word every time you change pom.xml you better use

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

in Shell.

Comment: Hi Vahid,
I have tried this but still got the same error.

Comment: @ChetanNakum are you sure jfairy dependency resolve? The jar file exist in your path ? I search and find this link : http://snacktrace.com/artifacts/io.codearte.jfairy/jfairy/0.5.2/io.codearte.jfairy.Fairy

Answer (score 0):

NoClassDefFound means the class was found, but could not be instantiated. Usually this is because of a problem when running the constructor. Check the Tomcat logs around the time you deployed the app to Tomcat.